# Using Matlab Regex to insert "disclaimer" at begining of multiple codes within multiple subfolders

Tags: python, regex, matlab, fopen, dir

I have a folder with multiple subfolders that all contain several files. I am looking to write a matlab code that will insert a commented out "disclaimer" on the top of every relevant code [c, python (.py not .pyc), .urdf, .xml (.launch, .xacro, .config)]

My current thought process is to first list out every subfolder within the main folder. Then search within each subfolder for the relevant codes. If a relevant code is found, the disclaimer is commented in the top of the code... (each language has a different disclaimer)

I am having a hard time piecing this all together.. any help?

```
data_dir = 'C:thedirectorytomainfolder':

topLevelFolder = data_dir;
if topLevelFolder == 0
    return;
end

% Get list of all subfolders.
allSubFolders = genpath(topLevelFolder);
remain = allSubFolders;
listOfFolderNames = {};

while true
    [singleSubFolder, remain] = strtok(remain, ';');
    if isempty(singleSubFolder)
        break;
    end
    listOfFolderNames = [listOfFolderNames singleSubFolder];
end

numberOfFolders = length(listOfFolderNames)

%% Process all (wanted) files in those folders
for k = 1 : numberOfFolders
    % Get this folder and print it out.
    thisFolder = listOfFolderNames{k};
    fprintf('Processing folder %s\n', thisFolder);

    % Get .xml files.
    filePattern = sprintf('%s/*.xml', thisFolder);
    baseFileNames = dir(filePattern);

filePattern = sprintf('%s/*.c', thisFolder);
baseFileNames = [baseFileNames; dir(filePattern)];

numberOfImageFiles = length(baseFileNames)
```

I'm having a hard time reading each relevant file and inserting the correct comment code at the beginning of the file... any help?

Answer (score 0):

Most of [matlab's methods for reading text files](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/ways-to-import-text-files.html) assume you are trying to load in primarily numeric data but one of them might still work for you.

Sometimes it's easier to `fopen` the file and then read lines with `fgetl` of `fread`. Because you're doing [low-level IO](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-text-data-files-with-low-level-io.html#br4ssin) you have to test for the end of file too with `while ~feof` or somesuch. You could store each line in a cell array, prepend it with a cell array of your disclaimer and then write back out with `fwrite`, converting the cell back to a string with `char`.

It'll be pretty cumbersome. Does it have to be matlab? If you have the option it might be quicker to do it in a different language - it would be less than twenty lines in shell, and ruby/python/perl are all more geared up for text processing, which isn't matlab's strongest point.